# How to store multiple data from each loop in one file

Tags: c

the code only stores the last value in the array in "Data.txt" I want to store every value
I have been trying to fix it for hours nothing seems to be working and no one have the same issue.
also in the "aff" function it basiclly does the same thing it shows me the last value
Thanks in advance to anyone who decide to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

  
// Structure of the employee
struct emp {
    char name[50];
    char depa[50];
    int hr;
    int age;
    int id;
};

FILE *f;


emp* add(emp *e,int n){
                    int i;
                    char p;
                    
    

emp *t;

int k;

t=(emp*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        printf("\nEnter Name : ");

        scanf("%s",&(t+i)->name);
        printf("\nEnter Departement(AVAILBLE DEPARTEMENT ARE IT): ");
        
        scanf("%s",&(t+i)->depa);
  
        printf("\nEnter Age : ");
        scanf("%d", &(t+i)->age);
  
        printf("\nEnter avearge hour of works(per week) : ");
        scanf("%d", &(t+i)->hr);
        k=((t+i)->hr)*40;//40 is minimum wage for each hour of work
        printf("Salary of The employe: %d\n",k);
  
        printf("\nEnter EMP-ID : ");
        scanf("%d", &(t+i)->id);
    
    
        
           f=fopen("Data.txt","w");
        if (f != NULL){
            fprintf(f,"%s\t\t",(t+i)->name);
            
    
            fprintf(f,"%s\t\t",(t+i)->depa);
            
    
            fprintf(f,"%d\t\t",(t+i)->age);
        
    
            fprintf(f,"%d\t\t",(t+i)->hr);
            
    
            fprintf(f,"%d\n",(t+i)->id);
         fclose(f);
    
             
        }
    
      
   
}

  printf("want to add more? Y/n \n");
  scanf("%s",&p);

  return t;
}

void aff(emp *e,int n){
int i;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Name :%s\n",e[i].name);
        printf("Departement: %s\n",e[i].depa);
        printf("Age: %d\n",e[i].age);
        printf("Hour of work: %d\n",e[i].hr);
        printf("Id: %d\n",e[i].id);

    }
}

//int* modf(int *t,int n,)

//int del(int *t,int n,emp *e){
//  
//  int a;
//  printf("position of the entry you want to delete?");
//  
//}





int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int c;
    emp e;
    emp *k;
    k=&e;
    
    
    int n;
    emp *t;
    t=&e;


    char p;

    ka:
    printf("Welcome To The employe management Menu\n");
    printf("1.Add employes?\n");
    printf("2.show all employes?\n");
    printf("3.Show all salaries?\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    switch (c){
        case 1:
e:
printf("How many employes you want to add?\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
            
add(k,n);

if(p=='y'){
    goto e;
    
}
else goto ka;
                break;
                case 2:
                    aff(k,n);
    }
    

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Every time you call `f=fopen("Data.txt","w");` the file is truncated. Call that once, before the loop and move `fclose(f);` to after the loop. Or open for appending.

Comment: Also, `t=(emp*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` is not allocating the correct amount of memory. Use `t = malloc(n * sizeof(*t));` or `t = malloc(n * sizeof(struct emp));`

Comment: Please also do yourself a favor and don't use `goto` ever, or at least not until you are much more proficient in C. Try `do{  }while( );` loops instead